# DoneDiscard activity - unable to set content layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I use this class ([source](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/donediscard/src/com/example/android/donediscard/DoneDiscardActivity.java?r=d4e5917c7b11ae0e49928483f7d172c37d66ec48) provided by Roman Nurik)
But i am unable so the the content layout (where i want to have a Edittext field).

```
public class AddActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
    tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
    tintManager.setStatusBarTintResource(R.color.black);

    // Inflate a "Done/Discard" custom action bar view.
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar().getThemedContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_done_discard, null);

    customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_done).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    finish();
                }
            });
    customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_discard).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // "Discard"
                    finish(); // TODO: don't just finish()!
                }
            });

    // Show the custom action bar view and hide the normal Home icon and title.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

This is the layout i want to set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/add_layout"
 >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/add_hint_title"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/info_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/add_hint_info"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

If i then try to use `setContentView(R.layout.add_layout)` it sets the layout into the actionbar. Does anyone know how to properly set the layout in this Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can call `setContentView(...)` directly after the call to `super.onCreate(...)`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);
```

or you can try this:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_layout, null);
setContentView(v);
```

Comment: Yes Thanks! With setContentView it didn't work but with the second way!